# Setting up a Dev->Test->Prod integration environment for SharePoint 2010

Tags: svn, sharepoint, testing

Broad(ish) questions:

1. Is it possible to set up a test-dev-prod integration environment for
   SharePoint development?
2. How do teams of developers normally collaborate on SharePoint
   development?
3. What is the recommended way to mirror a production setup for
   development purposes?
4. What is the best way to deploy changes into production?
5. How is version control (svn, git) handled?
6. How is server setup and configuration put into version control?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set up a dev/test/prod environment for SharePoint development.

The central product is the "Team Foundation Server" (TFS):

- You can define "Build Definitions" for every environment and additional deployment scripts.
- The team can work with the TFS-"Work Items"

  - Bugs
  - Test Cases
  - Tasks

The TFS can also manage a VM-based farm (including setup and config).

Check it out [here](https://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/overview)

Comment: What about data? Does TFS handle mirroring of data?

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, it’s completely possible to get ALM support when developing for SharePoint. Therefore, ALM story for SharePoint development is something definitively possible to achieve, but you will need to invest some time deciding the ALM platform to use (you can use TFS or you can use a combination of “inexpensive” ALM products such as Subversion, Mercurial and others…What I would recommend is to have a centralized development environment easy to setup and simple to access by the SharePoint development team. You might check the features and capabilities provided by some well-known Cloud Providers on the SharePoint development arena: Microsoft Azure, Amazon, CloudShare, FPWeb, etc.

Comment: "ALM" is an unintroduced acronym- you seem to be using it synonymously with "source control"- what does it stand for? This comment seems to be restating the question.